why sqlworkbench memory utilization is not reduced after query execution
I am working Redshift database and using SQLworkbench as a client tool. I have been observing high utilization on memory   during execution. After completion of query execution, memory is nor reduced. Since multiple team members are taking RDP on a single sever it is impacting to all as workbench terminate automictic after memory utilization reached to 90%+
Appreciate your help to sort this problem statement.
SQLworkbench tool will not crash/terminate.

Please clarify if you are using sql-workbench-j or MySQL Workbench for your project.  They are NOT the same product.

Yes, Workbench is a bad tool with a lot of memory leak issue. It eats up your memory, and crashes frequently. Unfortunately it is considered the best free MySQL GUI, so we have to live with it.
You can try to generate some bug report: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-reporting-bugs.html
